# Log4j appender logs more levels than expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I have the following `log4j2.xml` file for my Spring Boot project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %level %pid --- [%t] %c : %m%n"/>
        </Console>

        <JDBC name="DB" tableName="logs">
            <DriverManager connectionString="url" userName="username" password="$password"/>
            <Column name="TIM_TIMESTAM" isEventTimestamp="true"/>
            <Column name="DES_LOGGER" pattern="%c"/>
            <Column name="COD_JLEVEL" pattern="%level"/>
            <Column name="DES_LMESSAGE" pattern="%m}"/>
        </JDBC>

        <Async name="Async">
            <AppenderRef ref="DB"/>
        </Async>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Async"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In my `application-LOCAL.yml` I have the following logging configuration:

```
logging:
  path:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        type: trace
```

Apparently, this configuration makes the appender to log as if root level was `TRACE` instead of `INFO`, a behaviour which I'd like to avoid. How could I do this?

Comment: Are you using log4j 1.x or 2.x? The configuration file name should be log4j2.xml for 2.x.

Comment: @aled 2.x, the file is actually named `log4j2.xml`. I'll correct the name